# Сборка Makefile для DL POLY 4

Tags: makefile, fortran

Пытаюсь сделать сборку makefile для программы DL POLY 4, однако при выполнении команды `make gnu -f Makefile_MPI clean` выводится ошибка:

```
make LD=gfortran \
LDFLAGS="-O3" \
FC="gfortran -c" \
FCFLAGS="-O3" \
EX=DLPOLY.Z BINROOT=../execute master
make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/rasul/desktop/blya/source»
make[1]: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «master».  Останов.
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/rasul/desktop/blya/source»
Makefile_MPI:242: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «gnu»
make: *** [gnu] Ошибка 2
```

Краткое содержание makefile'a:

```
/*---CODE---*/

gnu:
    $(MAKE) LD=gfortran \
    LDFLAGS="-O3" \
    FC="gfortran -c" \
    FCFLAGS="-O3" \
    EX=$(EX) BINROOT=$(BINROOT) $(TYPE)

---------------------

master: message check $(OBJ_MOD) $(OBJ_ALL)
    $(LD) $(EXE) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ_MOD) $(OBJ_ALL)

# Message
message:
    @echo "DL_POLY_4 compilation in MPI mode"
    @echo
    @echo "'Use mpi_module' must change to 'Use mpi' in 'comms_module.f90'"
    @echo

# Check that a platform has been specified
check:
    @if test "${FC}" = "undefined"; then \
    echo; echo "*** FORTRAN90 compiler unspecified!"; \
    echo; echo "*** Please edit your Makefile entries!"; \
    echo; exit 99; \
    fi; \
    \
    if test "${LD}" = "undefined"; then \
    echo; echo "*** FORTRAN90 Linker-loaDer unspecified!"; \
    echo; echo "*** Please edit your Makefile entries!"; \
    echo; exit 99; \
    fi; \
    \
    mkdir -p $(BINROOT) ; touch dl_poly.f90

    /*---CODE---*/
```

Никогда не работал с `makefile` и `fortran`, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

рекурсивно запускается программа *make*, которой **не** передаётся аргумент `-f Makefile_MPI`.

соответственно этот экземпляр программы *make* пытается интерпретировать [первый из найденных в текущем каталоге файлов](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Arguments.html#Makefile-Arguments) с именем: `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, `Makefile`. и в этом файле (цитирую):

> Нет правила для сборки цели «master».

---

простейшее решение для обхода этой недоработки разработчиков — запускайте программу *make* с нужной целью, не забыв добавить все упомянутые в логе аргументы, **напрямую**:

```
$ make -f Makefile_MPI LD=gfortran LDFLAGS="-O3" FC="gfortran -c" FCFLAGS="-O3" EX=DLPOLY.Z BINROOT=../execute master
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все получилось!